# WCF Service hosted but when deployed doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I am new to WCF. This is an attempt for self hosted WCF Service.I tried to create my first WCF Service using `basicHttpBinding` but it gives me an error for

> 'Resource Not Found 404'.

I am using a console application for hosting my WCF & consuming it through a web application.
There is no issue in Hosting. When I browse the Service URL it runs cool even shows the WSDL.
Also shows me the message that I have created the service.
But when I try to consume the service through web application using another instance of `VS2013(Admin Mode)` then I get an exception stating:

> An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.ServerTooBusyException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

This exception is raised when I try to call the service method using the object of the proxy class.
This is the code in the App.config file of my Console Application

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="Hello_Service.HelloService" behaviorConfiguration="mexBehaviour">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Hello_Service.IHelloService"></endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="mexBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

This is the code in Program.cs of Console Application

```
using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Hello_Service.HelloService)))
        {
            host.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Service started @ " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

And this is how I am consuming the WCF on Web Application

```
HelloService.HelloServiceClient client = new HelloService.HelloServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IHelloService");
        Label1.Text = client.GetMessage(TextBox1.Text);
```

This is how I am Implementing the Interface in Service Class

```
public class HelloService : IHelloService
{

    public string GetMessage(string name)
    {
        return "Hello" + name;
    }
}
```

I am using Visual studio 2013 & Windows 8.1
I have turned down my firewall Settings & my Win Defender too. But still no success.
What could be the possible reason for this exception and how to get rid of it. 
Thanks for your time. Please Help.